# How to scroll to a particular co-ordinate in Test Complete

Tags: testcomplete, text-recognition

I have spied a notepad and text box of a notepad contains a string which will be visible only if you scroll down.

Now I am trying to perform a single click there via passing a rectangle co-ordinate to the Test Complete.So with that it is able to click if it is visible on the screen otherwise it fails saying :"there was an attempt to perform an action at a point which is beyond the screen"

Is there any way where we can scroll to the point of interaction before performing the action.

I tried with following steps to achieve that but its of no help.

```
testObj.setFocus()
testObj.hover()
testObject.MouseWheelScroll(an integer value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.. 
testObj.scrollIntoView(true);

I'm using this code and this is working fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching all day and I found simple solution.

```
obj.Keys("[Down][Down][Down]");
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).